# plt.errorbar for X string value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a dataframe as below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['one', 'two', 'three'], 'assess':[100,200,300]})
```

I want to build errorbar like this

```
c = 30
plt.errorbar(df['name'], df['assess'], yerr=c, fmt='o')
```

and of course i get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

I can convert string to float, but I'm losing value signatures and maybe there's a more elegant way?

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266187/matplotlib-cannot-plot-categorical-values or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510070/plotting-in-python3-histogram or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029560/plotting-categorical-data-with-pandas-and-matplotlib or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294586/categorical-data-in-subplots or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958068/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-line-with-categorical-data-on-the-x-axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib can indeed only work with numerical data. There is an [example in the matplotlib collection](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html) showing how to handle cases where you have categorical data. The solution is to plot a range of values and set the labels afterwards using `plt.xticks(ticks, labels)` or a combination of `ax.set_xticks(ticks)` and `ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`.

In your case the former works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['one', 'two', 'three'], 'assess':[100,200,300]})

c = 30
plt.errorbar(range(len(df['name'])), df['assess'], yerr=c, fmt='o')
plt.xticks(range(len(df['name'])), df['name'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanx! I tried to use df.index but in ticks got an error